# Updating the width of NSTextField based on length of string

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I want to make a label that change its size depending on the size of the string value that it will show. Currently I am doing this:

```
[tfScroll setStringValue:strScoller];
[tfScroll sizeToFit];
```

However this is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: sizeToFit is not what you need. Just get the length of your text and change the width of the textField.

Comment: What is not working? Is the field not changing size or are other views not rearranging around it? Or something else? `sizeToFit` does resize a label to fit its contents but that is all it does. Your two lines of code should resize the label. Quick visual check is to give the label a background color, you will see the area the label is covering.

Comment: Cocoa Auto Layout provides ways of doing this sort of thing automatically.

Comment: @noa : can you explain how ?

Comment: Take a look at Auto Layout tutorials. The intro video from WWDC 2012 is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trying to resize the fields's height, this may works:

```
CGRect frame = tfScroll.frame;
frame.size.height = tfScroll.contentSize.height;
tfScroll.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 5):

If your tfScroll is NSTextField:

```
CGRect frame = tfScroll.frame;
frame.size.width = tfScroll.attributedStringValue.size.width+somepoints;//(somepoints=8)
tfScroll.frame = frame;
```

I did not find NSTextfield.contentSize.